# Is it possible to design circle using xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is possible to design circle like the attached image.
I want to create login page like attached image. [image: Login page]

Is there any way to create login page like attached image using Xamarin forms.

Comment: I guess this is a background image. Not custom shapes created and attached to the ContentPage.

Comment: There is always a way. However, it is unclear whether you mean the rounded corners on the entry fields. Or is it the background you are talking about?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/

Comment: Thanks for reply @Cheesebaaron Im talking about the background circle with speech bubble arrow like attached  image.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can either use images, or you can use a SkiaSharp canvas which has support for drawing shapes (like circles) or SVGs.

Comment: Use font awesome … https://fontawesome.com/search?p=1&q=Speech%20bubble&s=solid%2Cbrands

Answer (score 1):

export the image in the format you need. No need to do it by Xamarin